# Rails iteration with some smarts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, algorithm

I'm putting together a little game where people are voting to see two other people are a good match based on some interests they've previously entered and I'm having trouble getting the code to do what I want. We have some data about their "friends" and I'd like to do the following:

1. Select one of their "friends"
2. Find a match of that friend
3. If I can't find any friends' matches that I previously voted on, get a random match

I'd like steps 1 and 2 to be somewhat random so they don't see the friend each time. I am recording the votes now, so I do have a list of their votes already. This is what I have so far, but can't figure out how to put the two together.

```
found_new_match = false

#Try connected users first
# connected_users = current_user.get_connected_users
connected_users = []

unless connected_users.blank?
  user = connected_users.shuffle.first
  @match = user.matches.first
end

# Here i'd like to detect whether we got through all our connections' matches
while found_new_match == false do 
  found_new_match = true if @match = current_user.get_random_new_match
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the supporting logic of your code (getting connected users) works correctly and your question is about how to collapse this logic into a single line, the following should work fine:

```
  @match = current_user.get_connected_users.shuffle.first.try(:matches).try(:first) || current_user.get_random_new_match
```

If you factored the "first match of a user" (`user.matches.first`) into its own accessor method, you could skip the terrible looking `.try(:matches).try(:first)`.  You could further factor the "first random match" into a convenience method on `User`, such that the code would shorten even further into:

```
  @match = current_user.get_random_connected_match || current_user.get_random_new_match
```

assuming "get_random_connected_match" does the act of getting the connected users, shuffling out an option, and extracting the first match from that. Repeat refactoring ad nauseum.

Comment: Thanks! The reason I had put up .first initially was because I just wanted to get back a result, but it's likely that the .first option will have already been voted on, so I'd like the next one after that and so and I'm just not sure how to iterate through those options.

Answer (score 0):

I took your advice and went with:

```
@match = current_user.get_random_connected_match || current_user.get_random_new_match
```

In my method, I have :

```
connected_users = self.get_connected_users.map(&:id)
my_voted_matches = self.votes.map(&:matching_id)

Matching.first(:conditions => ["id NOT IN (?) AND (user_id IN (?) OR matched_id IN (?))", my_voted_matches.join(","), connected_users.join(","), connected_users.join(",")], :order => "RAND()")
```